# Where do I find the Ebony Warrior?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I'm a level 173 Nord. I checked each city and town yet I haven't been able to fight the Ebony Warrior. I have all the DLC that exist for for this game yet no matter where I go, I can't find him.

I've even checked Raven Rock, Tel Mithryn, and Skaal village but there is no sign of him. I've fought quite a lot of legendary dragons and I know that they appear when the Ebony Warrior decides to challenge you.

If you could me that would be great cause I've been itching for a good fight in an long time. I'm on Xbox 360.

Plus when I go on random rampages as a vampire lord I never see the ebony warrior anywhere just a ton of guards and a few townsfolk. (I go on rampages cause I can't find him)

Comment: How doesn't it help you?  Just asking the question again doesn't really give us much more to work with.

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't help you, **edit your question to help differentiate it**. Why doesn't it help? What is missing? What doesn't work? What have you tried? If you don't help us we can't help you.

Comment: I'd try going into the [major cities](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cities) one by one, and waiting for an in-game hour or two in each city, and see if he approaches you.

Comment: okay guys today I ran into the ebony warrior in windhelm after doing a thief quest while invisible and I had on a full suit of nordic carved armor and he only brought my health down to about 800, so not really a good fight but still I got to fight him so thanks

Answer (score 0):

If he's already challenged you, he's at the Last Vigil, east of Shor's Stone in the Rift. If he hasn't challenged you, you can't find him. He has to find you, and he will only appear in a city. Try going to a hold capitol and spend some time wandering the streets. Perhaps avoid going on any rampages, since he seems to show up when you *aren't* busy with combat.

Comment: he hasnt challenged me yet guys or else I wouldn't be asking